# Preventing conflicting updates in Postgres

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql, transactional

I have a `"users"` table with a `"state"` column that is `jsonb`. The logic for updating this state is complicated and is implemented in a "true" programming language (e.g. JavaScript).

I have *multiple* servers providing an API for updating the state. The load balancing between these servers is non-deterministic, so update requests might not always go to the same server.

The API will grab the current state (`SELECT`), run the function to update it (`updateState`) and then update the database (`UPDATE`) with the result.

It might look like this:

```
const updateHandler = async (id) =>
  const { state } = await db.one(
    `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $<id> LIMIT 1`, 
    { id });

  const nextState = updateState(state);

  await db.query(
    `UPDATE users SET state = $<nextState> WHERE id = $<id>`, 
    { id, nextState });
});
```

Because I have multiple servers, I want to ensure that when the state is updated, it is the result of calling `updateState` on the `state` value that is already there. Each server should have to queue (or perhaps throw an error) if another server is already performing an update.

What is the best strategy for doing this?

Comment: Unrelated but `LIMIT 1` slows things down. If you really need a LIMIT then you also need an ORDER.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Optimistic Locking Pattern`, you need just check the current state to validate your transaction

```
UPDATE users
SET    state = $<nextState>
WHERE  id = $<id> and state=$<currentState>
```

Check the nb row updating to detect the conflict :

- 1 row => it's ok
- 0 row => you have a conflict (another process have
  already update the same id data)

Comment: That's *optimistic locking*, a good option. The alternative is *pessimistic locking*: a `FOR UPDATE` clause in the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: So in this solution I will know if an update has actually occured based on the number of rows returned from the update (0 or 1)